# Trouble Importing .csv file when using MetaboAnalystR package

Tags: r, csv

I am a very novice R user and am having difficulty importing my .csv file using the "Import Dataset" button in RStudio. I have tried looking at similar questions others have asked to no avail. I have went through my data set and made sure all spaces are replaced with _ and that none of my metabolites have repeating names. However, I keep getting the same error message.

Here is my code from the console and resulting error messages:

```
ANOVA2fdr <- read.csv("C:/Users/earha/OneDrive/Metabolomics/Second Analysis/Analyses/AOVA2fdr/ANOVA2fdr.csv")
View(ANOVA2fdr)
library(MetaboAnalystR)
mSet<-InitDataObjects("conc", "ts", FALSE)

[1] "MetaboAnalyst R objects initialized ..."
Warning message:
In Cairo::CairoFonts(regular = "Arial:style=Regular", bold = "Arial:style=Bold",  :
CairoFonts() has no effect on Windows. Please use par(family="...") to specify the desired font - see ?par.

mSet<-SetDesignType(mSet, "g2")
mSet<-Read.TextData(mSet, ANOVA2fdr, "rowts", "disc");

<simpleError in data.table::fread(fileName, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE,     blank.lines.skip = TRUE, data.table = FALSE): input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r>
[1] "Using slower file reader ..."
<simpleWarning in if (formatStr == "txt") {    dat <- try(read.table(fileName, header = TRUE, comment.char = "",         check.names = F, as.is = T))} else {    dat <- try(read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE, comment.char = "",         check.names = F, as.is = T))}: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used>
[1] "Using slower file reader ..."
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
'file' must be a character string or connection
In addition: Warning message:
In if (formatStr == "txt") { :
he condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
[1] "Data format error. Failed to read in the data!"
[1] "Make sure the data table is saved as comma separated values (.csv) format!"
[1] "Please also check the followings: "
[1] "Either sample or feature names must in UTF-8 encoding; Latin, Greek letters are not allowed."
[1] "We recommend to use a combination of English letters, underscore, and numbers for naming purpose."
[1] "Make sure sample names and feature (peak, compound) names are unique."
[1] "Missing values should be blank or NA without quote."
[1] "Make sure the file delimeters are commas."
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: At what point are you getting the error? After the `Read.TextData()` line?

Comment: @Phil, that is correct. I am getting the error after running the "Read.TextData()" line.